# php curl code is not working on specific sites although scripts do

Tags: php, curl

I have created this code:

```
<?php
    $requesturl = "https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl";
    $ch = curl_init($requesturl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    echo curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

about a month ago that I created this script it had worked fine, but now it is working fine on many sites but it does not work on google and even youtube (By "not working" I mean it stays stock on loading i.e. the circle is spinning without anything happening).
I can access these two from my browser without any problem!

I came up with the idea that this problem goes back to curl itself.
I copied glype (proxy script) to the directory of EasyPHP (that is used for local hosting) and I put the `https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl` in the box and hit enter. I saw that it is working, so the curl has got no problem.

After this I thought that the problem is from my code.
So I decided to test it on my real host on the internet and I interestingly saw that my code is working fine there! It echoes back google.com to the browser.

Now Im out of idea .. I even cleared dns cache and it did not helped.
What should I do ?

Comment: How often do you fetch those sites? If it is too often you might be blocked.

Comment: Just curious: Does it work locally when replacing the last `setopt` line with `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://example.com');` ?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider If what you say is true then how can I access those through my web browser ?

Comment: Just a hint, not a solution: some sites want to have a `USER_AGENT` set to (kind of) make sure you're a real person.

Comment: @Siguza replaced it. still nothing happening.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite some things you can/should test.
I start with the basic tcp connection: In case you can use the [sockets extension](http://docs.php.net/sockets) you might try

```
<?php
$host = 'www.google.com';

echo "<p>gethostbyname</p>\r\n"; flush();
$addr = gethostbyname($host);
if ( $addr===$host ) {
    die('could not resolve host');
}

echo "<p>socket_create</p>\r\n"; flush();
$socket=socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
if ( !$socket ) {
    die('could not create socket');
}

echo "<p>socket_connect</p>\r\n"; flush();
if ( !socket_connect($socket, $addr, 443) ) {
    die('could not coennect socket');
}
echo 'Done.';
```

to check whether the hostname can be resolved and the connection established.